# is there a way to tell which store the app is currently in?

Tags: react-native

I have been looking everywhere and can't find a solution except requesting the GPS location of a user. Are there any way for information such as country to be provided once someone has downloaded the app?

Example:

Allow download in America
Allow download in Spain

Depending on the region we would default to a specific language. Or is there no way except GPS locator? Because if that is the case maybe asking which language preferable upon signing up would be my solution.

Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, no need for the GPS to suggest the language. Use system preferences, I think this package could help https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need to get the user country without using GPS. Well, you can use **freegeoip.app/json** API that returns *lat, long, country name, state, city/town* of the current location of the user in JSON format.

```
state = {
    countryData:null,
  };
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://freegeoip.app/json/', {
           method: 'GET'
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
           console.log(responseJson);
           this.setState({
        countryData: responseJson,
           })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
        });
  }
<Text>{this.state.countryData.country_name}</Text>
```